# Hive insert hangs in recude at 99%

Tags: hive

I am trying to insert into a partitioned Hive table.
Maps succeeds. But the reduce gets to 99%. Then it stays at 99% and doesn't finish. This goes on for hours without any result.

Can somebody let me know what could be the reason?

Note: I tried to insert into a non partitioned parquet table and it succeeded.
But I want to create a partitioned table.

The logs as seen in Hue is as below:

---

```
INFO  : 2017-11-21 15:42:56,672 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 99%, Cumulative CPU 76743.67 sec

INFO  : 2017-11-21 15:43:57,045 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 99%, Cumulative CPU 76816.54 sec

INFO  : 2017-11-21 15:44:57,332 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 99%, Cumulative CPU 76892.15 sec
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are inserting data into table with Dynamic Partition logic in DML and if your data is large , then it creates problem in the reducer.

If possible, please try to pass the the partition values manually in the DML through parameterization , if you already know about the partition values from any source.

Root cause of the problem, Reducer is executing 'DISTINCT values ' of partition column.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Since I am new to Hadoop, I am not able to understand your comments .  
the table is huge cdr table containing one month data and  the partition created is call_year, call_month. 
I am trying to populate this table with one year data ( one month at a time ).
Below is the sql i am using   ---- 

insert into cdr_table_tst  partition(CALL_year, call_month )
select a.*,
year( calltimestamp ) call_year,
month(calltimestamp ) call_month
from default.cdr_2017jan  as a  
DISTRIBUTE BY CALL_year, call_month;